# Bringing jQuery live('click') back to life after die()

Tags: jquery

I have a function assigned to a click event on a calendar - I need the click event in `live()` because the standard `.click()` does not bind itself to the newly displayed days when you switch months in the calendar - which triggers some AJAX based on the calendar date selected.

I need to prevent the user from firing any more AJAX until the previous request has completed so achieved this by immediately unbinding the click listener with `.die('click')`. However, I am unable to bring the eventWrap click listener back to life again with `$('.eventWrap').live('click')` from within itself it would appear.

Is there a solution to my problem?

```
$('.eventWrap').live('click', function() {
     $('.eventWrap').die('click');

     do ajax stuff

     //bring the .eventWrap click listener back to life
     //$(.eventWrap).live('click'); does not work as I had hoped

}
```

Comment: `on` and `off` api or `bind and unbind` event? might be the one you are looking for? :) let me know how it goes bruv!

Comment: Run away from .live() and associated functions, they're deprecated.

Comment: `live()` has been zombified, use `on` or `delegate` instead :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add a class within the click, and only do ajax if the class doesn't exist

```
$('.eventWrap').live('click', function() {
    if( ! $('.waitingForAjax').length ){
        $('.eventWrap').addClass('waitingForAjax');

         do ajax stuff- use removeClass() within the ajax success handler
    } else{
        alert('Waiting for last ajax to complete');
    }   
});
```

Use `on()` instead of `live()` if using jQuery 1.7

Comment: This was the perfect solution to my issue. As others have mentioned I should be leaving live() behind but in a rush, this was the quick fix I needed. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

#### According to your code

As live is deprecated so use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) and [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off)

```
$('.eventWrap').on('click', function() {
     $('.eventWrap').off('click');

});
```

To rebind that off event use

```
$('.eventWrap').on('click');
```

#### if append to DOM after page load

if you `.eventWrap` append to dom after page load then you should go for delegate event

```
 $('#container').on('click', '.eventWrap',function() {
     $('#container').off('click', '.eventWrap');
});
```

To unbind that event

```
     $('#container').off('click', '.eventWrap');
```

Here `#container` point to the container of `.eventWrap` that belong to DOM at page load, you may have some other selector to point that container of `.eventWrap`.

#### but better would be use refactoring

```
    function offmyevent() {
       $('#container').off('click', '.evetWraooer');
    }


    function offmyevent() {
       $('#container').on('click', '.evetWraooer');
    }

   $('#container').on('click', '.eventWrap',function() {
         offmyevent();
         callMyAjax();
   });
```

So for ajax call issue

```
function callMyAjax() {
  $.ajax({
      url: '',
      data: '',
      method: '...',
      success: function() {
         onmyevent(); // 
     }
  })
```

Comment: I tried using on/off previously, however it does not bind the click event to the calendar dates as they are loaded after the DOM has loaded by jQuery. This is why I am stuck with having to use live.

Comment: You simply used .on() the wrong way. You need to look at the API and use it in "delegate" mode, and delegate listening to an ancestor that doesn't get destroyed.

Comment: @GregPettit Hi mate, You should see my answer carefully, I also write abotu delegate mode

Answer (score 1):

To turn `on()` and `off()` event handlers, you need to pass the function through also.

```
$("#container").on("click", ".eventWrap", eventWrapClicked);

function eventWrapClicked(){
    $("#container").off("click", ".eventWrap", eventWrapClicked);

   //Do your AJAX -- on success, reapply the clickhandler.
   // $("#container").on("click", ".eventWrap", eventWrapClicked);
}
```